# C# WPF Control an other Application and Login into Websites

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, controls, spy++

I´m creating a System which will automatically log me in applications and websites(Origin,Steam,Skype,Facebook,Twitter,Reddit)

I started to code the login for the Programm.
With steam it was easy.

```
 Process.Start("C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe", "-login " + Username + " " + Password + "");
```

But Origin and Skype don't support the process startparameter -login

I already found somthing like that [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/clicking-a-button-in-another-application/)

I understand not really much as I'm a beginner.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this, or a better explanation for that one in the link.

Login into Websites:
I'm starting the Webbrowser from WPF to login (is it possible to do it with firefox maybe ?)

To login in Facebook I can use this code:

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com"); 

        string postData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", us, pw);

        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); 
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); 
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
        newStream.Close();
        SecureString pws = new SecureString();
        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        foreach (var item in pw)
        {
            pws.AppendChar(item);
        }


        w1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1", "", byteArray, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Whats the problem when I change URL to another Website ?
This code should be universal or what did I wrong ?

ty for your Help :)

*push